# React - Call function from non-parent component with state from separate component

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to call a function from an AppBar with the state from a child component, like so

```js
// App.js
<BrowserRouter>
    <Nav />
    <Routes>
       <Route exact path={"/"} element={<MyComponent/>}/>
    <Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```js
//Nav.js
function Nav() {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <button onClick={logChildState}>Get State</button>
    </div>

  )
}
```

```js
// MyComponent.js
function MyComponent() {
   const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({
      Some state values....
   })

   return (
      <div>
        <input />
       ...more components...
     </div>

   )
}
```

```js
logChildState() == "Some state values...."
```

The goal is to have the AppBar have a button with a function call that captures the state of MyComponent. As this is a simplified example, I will just say that the state should exist in the child, and it's not possible to hoist the state to App.js - because of this, I don't see a way to accomlish what I'm looking for easily, I've looked at possibly achieving this using context or an observable but it would be quite messy.

I'm wondering what the best way to tackle this kind of issue would be, or if my best choice would just be to have the "button" in Nav.js in the MyComponent.js.

Thanks

Comment: Do you think [jotai](https://jotai.org/) and work for you, it does not need parent-child hierarchy and reduces re-renders

Answer (score 0):

You can add the function as a prop like this:

```
//Nav.js
function Nav({logChildState}) {
 return (
    <div>
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
       <button onClick={() => logChildState('send this message')}>Get State</button>
    </div>

  )
}
```

And in your app Component you can simply take it as a prop like this:

```
<Nav logChildState = {logChildState}/>
```

and if you want to print the message comming from Nav component simply do this in App.js

```
const logChildState = (message) => {
  console.log(message);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @HenryDev, thanks for the comment.

The challenge I'm facing is that I'm trying to (e.g) console.log with the state from child component, based on a onClick function from the nav.

In this case, I'm not able to pass logChildState to nav and have its "context" / parameters come from MyComponent.

Any thoughts?